# Write Data To File in Python Gives Error Related to UNICODE

Tags: python, file-io

I am basically parsing data from XML using SAX Parser in Python.

I am able to parse and print. However I wanted to put the data to a text file.

sample:

```
def startElement(self, name, attrs):
    file.write("startElement'"+ name + " ' ")
```

While trying to write some text to a test.txt with above sample code, I get below error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'unicode'
```

Any help is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using an open file. You are using the [`file` *type*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file). The `file.write` method is then unbound it expected an open file to be bound to:

```
>>> file
<type 'file'>
>>> file.write
<method 'write' of 'file' objects>
>>> file.write(u'Hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'unicode'
```

If you have an already opened file object, then use that; perhaps you have an **attribute** named `file` on `self`:

```
self.file.write("startElement'" + name + " ' ")
```

but take into account that because `name` is a Unicode value you probably want to encode the information to bytes:

```
self.file.write("startElement'" + name.encode('utf8') + " ' ")
```

You could also use [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to create a file object that'll accept Unicode values and encode these to a given encoding for you when writing:

```
file_object = io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

but then you need to be explicit about always writing Unicode values and not mix byte strings (type `str`) and Unicode strings (type `unicode`).

Comment: @Dinakar: but you didn't put that in a place that makes it a global. Your `startElement` method looks up the name `file` as a global, and finds the built-in.

Comment: @Dinakar: in other words, you'll need to show us more code if you want us to help find why the method doesn't find your file.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: I think this is helping.  But i get below error now:    file = open("out.txt", "w", "utf-8")
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: I am a learner. Can you please elaborate on "but then you need to be explicit about always writing Unicode values and not mix byte strings (type str) and Unicode strings (type unicode)."

Comment: @Dinakar: you are missing the `encoding` keyword. You are trying to set the `buffer` parameter instead.

Comment: @Dinakar: as for mixing Unicode and byte strings, please read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html as a good introduction to the issues.

Comment: @Martjin Thanks a lot. The information and the introduction tutorial has been quite useful and helped fixing the issue.